# UIImageView that takes left corner inside UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitextview

How can I write Xcode objective-C code for UITextView with UIImageView on top left corner and string starts right next to UIImageView.

So UITextView text will not fill out the rectangle area. 
I thought about making a subclass of UITextView that contains UIImageView.  But then, i am stuck with text positioning that should not cross the UIImageView area.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you all for comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 150, 100, 60)];
    [textView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 0, 0)];//30**
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 60)];//30**
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
    [textView addSubview:imageView];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
```

30** =  imageWidth = edgeInset for LeftSide

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
   myTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    myTextField.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downArrow.png"]];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: the question is for UITextView not UITextField

Answer (score 2):

**Try it dude...**

```
func addButtonInTextField(image:UIImage, forTextField text:UITextField) ->UIButton{

    let kImageEdge:CGFloat = 2.0
    let ysFix_button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    ysFix_button.frame = CGRectMake(text.frame.origin.x, text.frame.origin.y, text.frame.size.width / 7, text.frame.size.height)
    ysFix_button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(kImageEdge,kImageEdge,kImageEdge,kImageEdge)
    ysFix_button.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    text.rightView = ysFix_button
    text.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    return ysFix_button
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope Below Links may help you achieve what you want.

1) [Classes extends abilities of UILabel, UIButton, UITextField and UITextView]
https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGViews

2)  A more powerful UITextView.
https://github.com/fsjack/JKRichTextView